# 'is lying' vs 'lying"

Tags: verb-forms, syntax, present-continuous

I'm trying to figure how to reduce my use of words like 'is', 'are' and 'being'.

> 1. A dog is lying on the floor.
> 2. A dog lying on the floor.

Why should I always write "A dog is lying"?  I think the second one gives the same meaning and is short and sweet.

Comment: Why should you reduce use of the verb *BE*? Forms of this verb are very frequent in all sorts of English because they are **needed** in many, many circumstances, not because they are overused. You cannot form a progressive or a passive construction without a form of *BE*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Lying* is a present participle, a **non-finite** form (see the [**verb-forms**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/verb-forms/info) tag wiki).

**An independent clause** (complete sentence) **requires a *finite* verb.**

- The ***finite*** forms of *lie* which agree with the third-person singular dog are *lies* (non-past) or *lay* (past).
- A non-finite form (infinitive *lie*, present participle *lying*, past participle *lain*) may be combined with a finite form of an auxiliary verb to form a finite 'synthetic' construction (*has lain*, *is lying*).

But a non-finite form without a finite auxiliary cannot act as the main verb in an independent clause; it can only act as a noun, adjective or preposition.

*A dog lying on the floor* is thus not a complete clause but only a noun phrase: the noun *dog* modified by the participle phrase *lying on the floor* acting as an adjective. The entire phrase acts as a noun **within** a sentence; syntactically it is no different from *a yellow dog* or *a vicious dog*.

> Joe kicked [a dog lying on the floor]. ... Joe kicked [a yellow dog].   ... Joe kicked it.
>   [A dog lying on the floor] growled at me. ...  [A vicious dog] growled at me. ... It growled at me.

If you really ***must*** avoid using the verb *BE* you may employ a finite form of *LIE* and write:

> A dog lies on the floor.

But unless you are constructing a description or narrative cast throughout in the 'present tense', it is very unlikely that this way of saying it would be idiomatic.